# Access "optional" fields of Info parameter in Chrome extension context menu onclick function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

From the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contextMenus#method-create) it seems that the `Info` parameter that is passed to the `onclick` function can contain information like `"parentMenuItemId"` or `"mediaType"`.

However, when I create a context like the following the "info" object only contains the fields that are not listed as "optional" in the documentation.

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
   title: "Log Info",
   id: "log_info",
   contexts:["page"], 
   onclick: function(info, tab) {
      console.log(info);
      console.log(tab);
   }
});
```

**Question**

Should these fields be available to me somewhere, and if so, how can I access them?

Comment: Instead of speculating, what happens if you try to access the optional properties like info.srcUrl. Don't think they are always available tho, hence the "optional" label.

Comment: They don't exist.  As in the example, I'm logging Info to console; the fields simply aren't in it.